# Синтаксически правильное написание фразы

Tags: синтаксис, фразеология

Как правильно написать: "ходатайствовать в Росрыболовстве" или "перед Росрыболовством"?

Answer (score 1):

Правильно: **ходатайствовать  перед Росрыболовством**.

Возможны три варианта сочетаемости для этого глагола:

ХОДАТАЙСТВОВАТЬ: 1) **о чем** (об изменении графика); 2) **за кого-что** перед кем (за медсестру перед главврчом): 3) с придаточным изъяснительным (союз **ЧТОБЫ**).

**Пример:** Я сам буду **ходатайствовать перед всеми инстанциями**, чтобы автор понёс наказание.